# tkinter scrolled window in dynamic(add/delete widgets at runtime) environment

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import string

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

class ScrollableFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.scrollbar_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar_x = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_y.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_x.set)

        self.scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", expand=False)
        self.scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_frame_configure)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Up>", lambda event: self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units"))
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Down>", lambda event: self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units"))
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Left>", lambda event: self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1, "units"))
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Right>", lambda event: self.canvas.xview_scroll(1, "units"))

        self.pack(side="top", expand=True, fill="both")

    def on_frame_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def update_scrollbars(self):
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

class StringWidget(tk.Frame):
    ''''''
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        ''''''
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, kwargs)
        entry = tk.Entry(self)
        entry.insert(0, f"This is entry number = {id_generator()}")
        #entry.pack(pady=5, fill="both", padx=5, expand=True)
        entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Make the entry stretchable
        self.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)

class Editor(tk.Frame):
    ''''''
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        ''''''
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, kwargs)
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=['10','25', '50'], state="readonly")
        self.combobox.current(0)
        self.combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.change_callback) 
        self.combobox.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.widgets = []
        self.change_callback()
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)

    def change_callback(self, event=None):
        # Delete existing widgets
        for widget in self.widgets:
            widget.destroy()

        # Clear widgets list
        self.widgets = []

        # Create widgets
        for i in range(int(self.combobox.get())):
            sw = StringWidget(self)
            self.widgets.append(sw)

# Example usage:
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Scrollable Frame Example")

sf = ScrollableFrame(root)
#sf.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
ae = Editor(sf.scrollable_frame)
sf.update_scrollbars()
#sf.scrollable_frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
root.mainloop()
```

I'm creating a custom scrolled window widget in tkinter. The above code is working fine except two problems.

1. The *StringWidget* is not expanded till the end of the window. To see the desired effect, uncomment the last two commented lines, but now scrollbars doesn't work.
2. The border over riding problem as shown in the image. When contents of the window are longer then the size of the window, you can see the problem.

Comment: It worked under Python 3.12.1

Comment: For point 1, use `canvas.bind("<Configure>", ...)` and resize `self.scrollable_frame` accordingly (you would also need `self.scrollable_frame.pack_propagate(False)`). For point 2, try checking what widget owns that border. If it's the canvas, remove the border and add a border to the `ScrollableFrame` frame.

Comment: On Python 3.9.1 the problem can be seen if `sf.canvas.focus_set()` is inserted before `root.mainloop()`. The solution is to define `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` to 0 when declaring `Canvas`.